# jQuery - radio buttons that add/remove a class to their labels

Tags: jquery

I know this may sound too easy for many but I just can't figure this one out on my own, I don't get what I'm missing.

I have a set of radio buttons grouped in pairs. Each pair corresponds to an opt-in / opt-out section.

What I need is to toggle a class `.active` on the `<label>`.

**Here's my basic HTML:**

```
<td class="btn opt-in">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio1">
  </label>
</td>
<td class="btn opt-out">
   <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio2">
   </label>
</td>
```

**Here's my JavaScript** (it works partially):

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    };
});
```

With the above script I'm able to add the class to the label just fine, but not remove/toggle it.

Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/NNkeQ/2/)** for reference.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you click on specific `input:radio` is always `checked`.

Use this instead:

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
  $('input:radio[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']').parent().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});​
```

`$('input:radio[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']')` selects all radio elements with the same name as clicked. Read about [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NNkeQ/7/

Or just:

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    $('label:has(input:radio:checked)').addClass('active');
    $('label:has(input:radio:not(:checked))').removeClass('active');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NNkeQ/18/

Comment: This worked great! What does this part mean?:`'+$(this).attr('name')+']'`. Thanks rogal111.

Comment: Selects elements with attribute `name` equal to clicked radio. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I like the second solution, it's easier to understand and it uses pretty much the same amount of code. Thanks for the explanations rogal111.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a radio button no `click` event is sent to the one that just became *unchecked*.

You need to find the other radio buttons from the same group and remove the `active` class from those.

This would be simplest if all of the radio buttons in each group shared a sihgle parent (i.e. a table row), e.g:

```
$(this).closest('td').siblings().find('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: Alnitak, I see what you say. However, I have a pair of radio buttons per row, so I have many rows in my code. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Ricardo that's what I meant - one table row per pair.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. I see your structure is fine, but not sure why it doesn't work.